# Any known install iso images using MBR partition and BIOS only installer?

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb, bios, gpt, mbr

I have a legacy BIOS motherboard which has broken USB-HDD boot capability.  The manufacturer has stopped supporting it a long time ago although I subsequently obtained a slightly newer BIOS image and flashed it - no change.  It's a Foxconn G31MV.  There is no CD drive and only a pre- SSL/TLS bug crippled but basically working Fedora 18 install on the internal disk.

The BIOS hangs upon !insertion! let alone attempt to boot from the USB device whenever a GPT with UEFI boot partition is present on the USB stick.

I am able to boot from the USB stick if I create a MBR partition table and FAT32 partition, and writing a MBR manually I am able to load syslinux or grub2 from the stick.

I have been able to fudge loading a recent lubuntu installer kernel via extlinux (creating an additional Linux partition and simply copying the content of the iso image to that partition) and also by manually installing grub MBR style and using the existing lubuntu grub config, however, the way the system is brought up I think there is an expectation that GPT partitions are present and so init fails early on when trying to mount squashfs into some location:

```
`(initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Device not found
Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs`
```

Any ideas to get a recent ubuntu/lubuntu/xubuntu on a system that has USB booting broken in such a way?

Do I need to resort to PXE boot or somehow run an installer from an image on the internal disk which then will overwrite the disk completely?

Comment: The standard Ubuntu ISO is both BIOS and UEFI. For BIOS boot it uses syslinux, & for UEFI, the UEFI directly reads /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Some tools that create installer may make it only BIOS or only UEFI. You can install in BIOS mode to gpt drive if you also have a bios_grub partition for grub to correctly install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: Can you point me at a tool that will rewrite the iso image as a MBR partition table type partitions and write the MBR such that syslinux is jumped to correctly please?  The GPT and EFI boot partition seem to be part of the problem.  I want to chain syslinux on a FAT32 partition marked bootable to the syslinux (really hyrbidised isolinux) on a subsequent partition.  I have tried extlinux and am able to get a kernel loaded but don't see what further preparation is needed, having looked at the isolinux configuration on the image.

Comment: I typically directly boot using grub2's loopmount. But have seen this image: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2 Shows Rufus and MBR & BIOS (UEFI CSM) boot.  Most really want gpt & UEFI. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off.